# Angle between two intersecting lines that appear on a cut face

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis, mathematical-physics, plane-geometry

I am given the equations of 2 thin planes in a rock.

Plane 1: $\mathbf r\cdot(0,3,-1) = -1$

Plane 2: $\mathbf r\cdot(1,0,1) = 1$

The entire set (the rock) is cut by the plane: $\mathbf r\cdot(-1,3,2) = 0$

I guess that these plane equations are int he format $\mathbf r\cdot\mathbf n =c$ where $\mathbf n$ is the vector of the normal to the plane, $\mathbf r$ is the vector to some point in the plane and $c$ a constant.

I am to find the angle between these which is meant to be given by $$\cos(\text{angle}) = -\frac7{\sqrt 3\cdot\sqrt{91}}$$

I am not sure how to prove this. I would have though that you would take the dot product of the normal of planes 1 & 2 to get this equation but that doesn't work out.

[The question in printed text form for context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfLgZ.jpg)

Comment: Do you have the answer to the first part of the question?

Comment: I wasn't really sure. i assume that 3 planes that are non-parallel can either intersect as 3 perpendicular planes, 3 disjoint planes (causing 3 parallel lines of intersection) or 3 planes intersecting that coincide with one common line of intersection.

Comment: If plane 1 and plane 2 intersect in a line L1, and plane 2 and plane 3 intersect in L2, then they will not intersect all 3 in a point, if L1 and L2 are parallel. This means `Cross[Cross[n1,n2],Cross[n2,n3]]=0`

Comment: Ok but surely that would mean also that planes 1 & 3 intersect at a line L3 too. Anyway how does this help in answering the question 3b?

Comment: If two are parallel, so is the third!

Answer (score 1):

If a plane $\mathcal{P}$ is defined by an equation

$$\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{n}=a$$

with $\textbf{r}$ the points of the plane, then each line which is definded by two points in the plane is perpendicular to $\textbf{n}$.

$$ \textbf{r}_1\cdot\textbf{n}=a,\quad\textbf{r}_2\cdot\textbf{n}=a,\quad\rightarrow\quad(\textbf{r}_1-\textbf{r}_2)\cdot\textbf{n}=0$$

Since two planes, intersect in a line, this line must be orthogonal to both normals of both planes. The intersection line has thus the direction $\textbf{n}_1\times\textbf{n}_2$.

In the original problem you are asked to compute the angle between two intersecting lines. The directions of those two lines are:

$$\textbf{s}_1=\begin{pmatrix}0\\3\\-1\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}-1\\3\\2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}9\\1\\3\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\textbf{s}_2=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}-1\\3\\2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-3\\-3\\3\end{pmatrix}$$

The vector angle can now be computed with the dotproduct:

$$\cos \theta=\frac{\textbf{s}_1\cdot\textbf{s}_2}{\left|\textbf{s}_1\right|\left|\textbf{s}_2\right|}=-\sqrt\frac{7}{39}$$

Comment: Yep I've just worked out the same thing. Thanks that is a very clear method.